# Is there a mechanical procedure within PA to reduce any ϕ to its simplest (in terms of the arithmetical hierarchy) logically equivalent form?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, incompleteness

The question is motivated because we know that the Turing computable sets of natural numbers are exactly the sets at level $\Delta_1^0$ of the arithmetical hierarchy. We also know that the finite Ramsey theorem is provable in PA, but it is a least $\Pi_2^0$ (I am not sure about this). So, does it mean that it is logically equivalent to a  $\Pi_1^0$ or $\Sigma_1^0$ formula? (because the set of Ramsey numbers is computable, right?)

**Continuation from answer below:**
Thanks a lot, very enlightening answer! My point however was not if every P would always end up in a $\Delta_0^0$ formula, but in the lowest one that in principle could exist (not necessarily $\Delta_0^0$). The motivation is to know if every ϕ that is provable in PA, is semantically equivalent (in N) to a $\Pi_1^0$ or $\Sigma_1^0$ formula.  My intuition (call it ***A***) is that if a ϕ is provable in PA, then the set defined by it must be computable, and so should be reducible to at least a $\Delta_1^0$. Although if P exists, that would imply that we could take any ϕ, reduce it to its simplest form, and know if it is provable or not (if its simplest form is above $\Delta_1^0$, then ϕ should not be provable). My guess is that either the procedure P does not exist, or that my intuition ***A*** is wrong (or both!)

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding here somewhere. PA proves only true formulas, so if $\phi$ is provable in PA, it must be true, and _therefore_ it is semantically equivalent to the formula $0=0$ which is $\Delta_0^0$. Formulas whose simplest form is $\Delta^0_1$ will be false for some inputs (because otherwise the simplest form would rather be the $\Delta^0_0$ formula $0=0$) and therefore such formulas _are not provable_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question in the body: Yes, *any* provable formula of whatever complexity is logically equivalent (given the axioms it is proved from) to $0=0$, which is even $\Delta_0^0$.

(Unless the logic the "proof" is done in is unsound, of course).

---

For the question in the title: No, such a mechanical procedure cannot exist, because if it did, we could use it to decide logical equivalence in general.

Suppose $\psi$ is a *sentence* and we want to know whether it is provable. Apply your hypothetical procedure to
$$\phi(x)\;\equiv\; \psi\land (x=x)$$
Now, it $\psi$ is provable, then the output of your procedure must be a $\Delta_0^0$ formula that is true for $x=0$, and checking that is a simple mechanical matter. Conversely *if* $\phi$ is logically equivalent to a $\Delta_0^0$ formula that is true for $x=0$, then by Gödel's completeness theorem, $\psi$ must be is provable.

---

In the comment below you amend the question so it is not about "provably equivalent in PA", but "semantically equivalent in the actual natural numbers". That's actually even worse from a decidability point of view -- truth about $\mathbb N$ is if anything *more* slippery than provability in PA.

A mechanical procedure for simplifying formulas behaves enough like a proof system that Gödel's incompleteness theorem applies to it, and we get:

**Theorem.** Let $P$ be some mechanical procedure which transforms arithmetical formulas into arithmetical formulas. Assume that the output of $P$ is always semantically equivalent (in $\mathbb N$) to the input. Then there exists a formula which $P$ does not transform into a semantically equivalent formula *on the lowest possible level* in the arithmetical hierarchy.

**Proof.** Call a sentence $\phi$ "good" if $P(\phi)$ is a $\Delta^0_0$ sentence that is true. (This concept of "goodness" will take the place of "provable" in our analogy to Gödel).

Our strategy will be to produce a $\phi$ that is *true* but not *good*. Then whatever $P(\phi)$ is, it has to be something that is true, because we're assuming $P$ preserves semantics. However, $P(\phi)$ cannot be $\Delta^0_0$, because then $\phi$ would be good, which it isn't. But then $P(\phi)$ must belong somewhere *higher* in the arithmetical hierarchy, which means that $\phi$ is a formula for which $P$ does not produce output of minimal complexity.

In order to find such a $\phi$, introduce Gödel numbers for formulas in the usual way. Since $P$ is a mechanical procedure, and the property of being a true $\Delta^0_0$ sentence is computable, by Church-Turing and other well-known stuff there is an arithmetical formula $\psi(x)$ that is true exactly when $x$ is the Gödel number of a good formula.

Following Gödel, we can then diagonalize and produce a sentence $\phi$ whose intuitive meaning is "I am not good". (Details of this diagonalization omitted; they are somewhat confusing, not particularly enlightening, and can be found in any good exposition of Gödel's proof).

I claim that $\phi$ is not good. Namely, assume to the contrary that $\phi$ *is* good. Then by our assumptions on $P$, $\phi$ must be semantically equivalent to true formula -- but then $\phi$ must itself be true, and since it asserts that $\phi$ is not good, we have reached a contradiction.

Therefore $\phi$ is *not good*. But since that is just what $\phi$ asserts, that means that $\phi$ is *true*! Q.E.D.

(Essentially the same argument works if you stipulate only that $P$ preserves semantics of formulas with exactly one free variable -- just add in a vacuous "$\cdots\land(x=x)$" at appropriate places in the argument, then).

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that my question had not the intended meaning that I had in mind.
The question would be the same, but instead of  "logical equivalence" I should have asked "that defines (or is satisfied by) the same set of natural numbers". I wonder if you could answer that too!

Comment: I could approve your answer and ask the new one separately, if you don't know the answer!

Comment: @julian: Answer updated.

Comment: thanks again Henning, I added a caveat in the original question, I wonder if you could address it!

Comment: I just realized my latter question doesn't make much sense, I found a more fundamental issue that I don't understand that I will ask separately.